# why does ejs and jquery(jquery-advanced-news-ticker) collide in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I have a node application I am using with ejs as my views driver, and i am trying to use [this](http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/) great plugin.

the code by itself works great, but when I load a dynamic code using ejs it stops. (if i try that with static html it works perffectly).

my ejs:

```
<% if(jobs !== undefined){ %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm newswell">
        <ul class="newsticker"><strong>
            <% jobs.forEach(function(item){ %>
                <li><%= item.message %></li>
            <% }); %>
        </strong></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

and the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
         $('.newsticker').newsTicker({
            max_rows: 1,
            speed: 600,
            direction: 'down',
            duration: 4000,
            pauseOnHover: 1
            });
      }, 2000);
   });
```

why do they collide?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using the plugin's method for stopping and then starting and it worked.